# maven surefire report plugin with forked tests

Tags: java, maven, selenium, surefire

I have two TEST-*.xml files being generated by forked tests running in parallel - these are two junit test clases.  For some odd reason, surefire is merging these 2 files into one report.  This report is also missing some information like Package name and Class information.

Here is an example of the TEST-*.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite failures="0" time="0.002" errors="0" skipped="0" tests="12" name="com.fidelity.mobile.core.RunCukesTest2">
<properties>
    <property name="java.runtime.name" value="Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment" />
    <property name="sun.boot.library.path" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin" />
    <property name="java.vm.version" value="22.1-b02" />
    <property name="java.vm.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
    <property name="java.vendor.url" value="http://java.oracle.com/" />
    <property name="path.separator" value=";" />
    <property name="guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check" value="true" />
    <property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" />
    <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io" />
    <property name="user.script" value="" />
    <property name="user.country" value="US" />
    <property name="sun.java.launcher" value="SUN_STANDARD" />
    <property name="sun.os.patch.level" value="Service Pack 1" />
    <property name="java.vm.specification.name" value="Java Virtual Machine Specification" />
    <property name="user.dir" value="C:\Workspaces\Fidelity\mobileTests" />
    <property name="java.runtime.version" value="1.7.0_03-b05" />
    <property name="java.awt.graphicsenv" value="sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment" />
    <property name="java.endorsed.dirs" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\endorsed" />
    <property name="os.arch" value="amd64" />
    <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="C:\Users\pguindon\AppData\Local\Temp\" />
    <property name="line.separator" value=" " />
    <property name="java.vm.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
    <property name="user.variant" value="" />
    <property name="os.name" value="Windows 7" />
    <property name="classworlds.conf" value="C:\Workspaces\Fidelity\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\launches\m2conf8811353436624661573.tmp" />
    <property name="sun.jnu.encoding" value="Cp1252" />
    <property name="java.library.path" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Python32;c:\Python32\Scripts;c:\selenium-2.24.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Users\pguindon\android-sdks;C:\Users\pguindon\android-sdks\platform-tools;C:\Users\pguindon\android-sdks\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\libs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\\bin;." />
    <property name="java.specification.name" value="Java Platform API Specification" />
    <property name="java.class.version" value="51.0" />
    <property name="sun.management.compiler" value="HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers" />
    <property name="os.version" value="6.1" />
    <property name="user.home" value="C:\Users\pguindon" />
    <property name="user.timezone" value="America/New_York" />
    <property name="java.awt.printerjob" value="sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob" />
    <property name="java.specification.version" value="1.7" />
    <property name="file.encoding" value="Cp1252" />
    <property name="user.name" value="pguindon" />
    <property name="java.class.path" value="/C:/Eclipse_Juno/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.1.0.20120529-1956/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar" />
    <property name="java.vm.specification.version" value="1.7" />
    <property name="sun.arch.data.model" value="64" />
    <property name="java.home" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre" />
    <property name="sun.java.command" value="org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -B clean test -Pparallel site" />
    <property name="java.specification.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
    <property name="user.language" value="en" />
    <property name="awt.toolkit" value="sun.awt.windows.WToolkit" />
    <property name="java.vm.info" value="mixed mode" />
    <property name="java.version" value="1.7.0_03" />
    <property name="java.ext.dirs" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext" />
    <property name="sun.boot.class.path" value="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\classes" />
    <property name="java.vendor" value="Oracle Corporation" />
    <property name="maven.home" value="C:\Workspaces\Fidelity\mobileTests\EMBEDDED" />
    <property name="file.separator" value="\" />
    <property name="java.vendor.url.bug" value="http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/" />
    <property name="sun.cpu.endian" value="little" />
    <property name="sun.io.unicode.encoding" value="UnicodeLittle" />
    <property name="sun.desktop" value="windows" />
    <property name="sun.cpu.isalist" value="amd64" />
</properties>
<testcase time="0.002" classname="Given I am on Google     " name="Given I am on Google     " />
<testcase time="0" classname="When I search for &quot;Orange&quot;      " name="When I search for &quot;Orange&quot;      " />
<testcase time="0" classname="Then I should see &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; in the search results       " name="Then I should see &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; in the search results       " />
<testcase time="0" classname="| &quot;Orange&quot; | &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; |    " name="| &quot;Orange&quot; | &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; |    " />
<testcase time="0" classname="Given I am on Google         " name="Given I am on Google         " />
<testcase time="0" classname="When I search for &quot;Banana&quot;          " name="When I search for &quot;Banana&quot;          " />
<testcase time="0" classname="Then I should see &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; in the search results           " name="Then I should see &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; in the search results           " />
<testcase time="0" classname="| &quot;Banana&quot; | &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; |        " name="| &quot;Banana&quot; | &quot;Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia&quot; |        " />
<testcase time="0" classname="Given I am on Google Maps               " name="Given I am on Google Maps               " />
<testcase time="0" classname="When I search for &quot;North Pole&quot;                " name="When I search for &quot;North Pole&quot;                " />
<testcase time="0" classname="Then I should see &quot;North Pole&quot; in the search results                 " name="Then I should see &quot;North Pole&quot; in the search results                 " />
<testcase time="0" classname="| &quot;North Pole&quot; | &quot;North Pole&quot; |              " name="| &quot;North Pole&quot; | &quot;North Pole&quot; |              " />
```

Here is my pom configuration:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Run*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <threadCount>${junit.threadCount}</threadCount>
                <forkMode>perthread</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```